# access entity framework entity with inheritance

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance

I have entity A. Entity B inherits entity A. For entity B there are o propertis generated by entity framework for accessing it's content. How can  access entity B?Do I have to provide my own methods, or can I force EF to cretae them?

what I do is:
B inhirits A
context.A - have access to entity A

but context.B does not exist. methods are not generated for accessing entity B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run queries on context.A it will return entities from whole inheritance hierarchy. So the result of `context.A.ToList()` will be all As and Bs. If you want to query only derived type you can use `context.A.OfType<B>().ToList()`

Comment: please tell me is it a bad practice to use OfType? IS this usage of refflection bad for perfomance?

Comment: It doesn't use reflection and it is absolutely correct approach.